# How to use Stream API with list of object array?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i have this method given below... how can I change this method in stream API.

```java
public List<AddNewSchoolBean> getEmployeeList() {

        List<AddNewSchoolBean> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            List<Object[]> empList = null;

            empList = Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst();

            if (empList.size() != 0) {
                for (Object[] obj : empList) {
                    AddNewSchoolBean bean = AddNewSchoolBean.builder()
                            .employeeId((obj[0]).toString())
                            .employeeName((obj[1]).toString())
                            .schoolName((obj[2]).toString())
                            .build();
                    list.add(bean);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Stream what? The method internally to use a stream? For it to return a `Stream<AddNewSchoolBean`? Not really clear what you want? Can you chanage `Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst()` to retrurn a `Stream` or is that always a `List`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to internally use a `java.util.Stream` I would suggest first to polish/cleanup your code a bit.

1. You don't need to split declaration and assignment of the `empList` variable
2. Move the conversion logic into a `private` method.
3. The `if` check for size doesn't add anything.

```java
public List<AddNewSchoolBean> getEmployeeList() {

    List<AddNewSchoolBean> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        List<Object[]> empList = Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst();
        for (Object[] obj : empList) {         
            AddNewSchoolBean bean = convert(obj);
            list.add(bean);        
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}

private AddNewSchoolBean convert(Object[] empArray) {
  return AddNewSchoolBean.builder()
                    .employeeId((empArray[0]).toString())
                    .employeeName((empArray[1]).toString())
                    .schoolName((empArray[2]).toString())
                    .build();
}
```

Now assuming you cannot change the `Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst();` you can use the `stream()` method on the `List` to convert it to a `java.util.Stream`. Then you can use `map` to convert the array into an object and finally collect to a list and return it.

```java
public List<AddNewSchoolBean> getEmployeeList() {
        List<Object[]> empList = Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst();
        return empList.stream()
                   .map(this::convert)
                   .toList();
}
```

This is assuming you are on JDK17 and you need ofcourse the aforementioned `convert` method.

Comment: can simplify `getEmployeeList` even further by not creating `empList` and making sure Dao.get() returns not null

Comment: Judging from the posted code in the question it already never returns null (judging from the size check). And yes you could simplify it more, but that is personal preference, I find this more readable.

Comment: you never know if it does or not :D but I agree ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the clean way is to map it to `AddNewSchoolBean` and then collect into List:

```
public List<AddNewSchoolBean> getEmployeeList() {
    try {
        List<Object[]> empList = Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst();

        return empList.stream()
                .map(this::createAddNewSchoolBean)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

private AddNewSchoolBean createAddNewSchoolBean(Object[] obj) {
    return AddNewSchoolBean.builder()
            .employeeId(String.valueOf(obj[0]))
            .employeeName(String.valueOf(obj[1]))
            .schoolName(String.valueOf(obj[2]))
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify even to this

```
@SneakyThrows
public List<AddNewSchoolBean> getEmployeeList() {
    return emptyIfNull(Dao.getEmpDetailsFromUserMst())
            .stream()
            .map(AddNewSchoolBean::new)
            .toList();
}
```

And your AddNewSchoolBean to have Object constructor

```
public class AddNewSchoolBean{
   String employeeId;
   String employeeName;
   String schoolName;

   public AddNewSchoolBean(Object[] data) {
       this.employeeId = String.valueOf(data[0]);
       this.employeeName = String.valueOf(data[1]);
       this.schoolName = String.valueOf(data[2]);
   }
}
```

Some additional imports required to make it simpler

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import static org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils.emptyIfNull;
```

In this Lambda expression, you first make sure your collection is not null, by using `emptyIfNull` (can be empty, but doesn't throw NPE), and then you stream through collection and map it to `AddNewSchoolBean` bean/entity via constructor. You can of course use `with` if you wish, but this looks cleaner. And then in the end you collect to `List`. Pleas note this is Immutable result, if you need Mutable, use `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Introducing lombok and commons collections for such a simple thing...

Comment: well, it depends on project. It's not a 1 class project and not leetcoode challenge, most of projects has Lombok nowadays, as well as apache commons for various other needs, so it's just a personal preference :)

Comment: Well I have an opinion on Lombok usage... And with the current state of the collections API I rarely have a need for the full blown Apache Commons Collections anymore.

Comment: Maybe, I've seen he catches the exception (but there shouldn't be any theoretically, unless o[1] is null with .toString()), so I added to be sure, same thing for `emptyIfNull`, just to be sure. If user is more aware of other parts of code he can easily strip down this even further

Comment: You can use `Objects.requireNonNullElse(empList, Collections.emptyList())` for this. No need to add an additional dependency.

Comment: I’d like to see the source for the claim that most projects use Lombok nowadays, I mean apart from “I use Lombok therefore everyone uses Lombok”.

Comment: @Holger #14 dependency by usage in mvnrespository tells something I guess

Comment: Well, I don’t use Maven, for example. And you won’t find out how many other developers don’t use Maven by looking at Maven repositories. But even for Maven projects, “#14 dependency” doesn’t say anything about the actual fraction of projects using it (“most projects” would imply that more than 50% of all projects are using it).